# Angular filter with ng-repeat not yet populated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have filter options such as dropdown which act as filters for displayed content.
Said content is called from a DB, and take a few ms to get displayed. during those few ms, I have lot of error linked to the filtering system. does someone knows how to keep them quiet?

HTML markup

```
<div class="user-content py-4 px-5">
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center pb-3" id="filters">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <select class="form-control" id="continent" ng-model="filter_continent">
                <option value="">continent</option>
                <option ng-repeat="con in continents" value="{{con}}">{{con}}</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <select class="form-control" id="category" ng-model="filter_cat">
                <option value="">catégorie</option>
                <option value="experience">Experience</option>
                <option value="explore">Explore</option>
                <option value="globe">Globe</option>
                <option value="sleep">Sleep</option>
                <option value="taste">Taste</option>
            </select>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-show="tipson" class="tips-widget text-center mb-5" 
         ng-repeat="item in userTips | filter:{category:filter_cat,continent:filter_continent}" 
         id="{{item._id}}" 
         style="background-image: url('{{item.cover}}');" 
         data-id="{{item._id}}" 
         ng-mouseenter="placeHover(item._id, item.lat)" 
         ng-click="show_tips(item._id)">
        <div class="background"></div>
        <p class="location"><span>{{item.country}}</span>, {{item.city}}</p>
        <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the errors I get. As soon as the ng-repeat source array is populated, errors stop.

```
Error: [filter:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/filter/notarray?p0=%7B%7D
```

**EDIT**

here is the instance code

```
 //USER TIPS
  $scope.userTips = {};


  $scope.user_tips = function(id){
    Tips.getByAuthorId(id)
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.userTips = data;
      });
  }
```

Comment: its very clear `userTips` is not an array, you can see its value using `<pre>{{ userTips | json}}</pre>`, please post above part in case its an array

Comment: I dont understand your answer tiona. how is it userTips is not an array of objects?

Comment: Please put the js code. Seems like the filter is searching for an array thats not there. is your model a declaration or an array instantiation?
 https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray

Comment: have you given it a try??

Comment: I've added the related bit of code

Comment: You're initialazing an object instead of an array, try `$scope.userTips = []`

Comment: yes that was it! thanks. Can you post this as an answer so I could validate it?

Answer (score 0):

Before you fetch the data from db, please check what userTips is initialized to. If it is not initialized, initialize it to an empty array.

Comment: see the update in my question. the empty array was initialized before it gets populated'